# python3 best method to yield minimum dict-pair in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, minimum

```
indices_video = [{'list_index': 0, 'stream_index': 0}, {'list_index': 2, 'stream_index': 5}]
```

Hello, I have a couple of lists like the above.

Is there a quick way to yield the pair {list_index, stream_index} which contains the minimum value of 'stream_index' in the entire list ?

In the above example the result would be {'list_index': 0, 'stream_index': 0}

I could loop through the list, but thought someone may have a better way.

Thanks

Comment: why not use `min` function?

Comment: Thank you RomanPerekhrest. That would have worked, however there was not enough information provided to create a working "min" line of code.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by passing a function used to determine the order as the `key` parameter:

```py
min(my_list, key=lambda x: x['stream_index'])
```

Comment: Thank you rudolfovic, that worked a treat.